# Rails compare same object's 1 field with another + addition of string in Active Record

Tags: ruby

I've two string fields which contains dates in string like field_1 = "2003.11.14" and I use them in ORM and they are working just fine. Now I want to compare 1 field value with another field's - 18.months. Here is a example

`User.where("users.field_1 > '#{Date.today - 18.months}' AND users.field_2 > (users.fields_1 - 18.months)")`

something like. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want comparison to work as you expect, then values should be stored as date type in database.

Comment: can not do that because the table has millions of records.

Comment: Then you end up in writing raw SQL query where you will convert string to date type and compare with given parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the advise of using raw SQL. I've tried it and it's working. Now I'm facing a new problem. What i want is convert string to date then minus some months like 3. How can I do that?

Comment: @NoManIlyas please ask a new question or search the system to see if your new question is already answered elsewhere.

Comment: Sure I'll check it its already answered or else I'll create a new one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support data calculations in SQL. Something like this should work.

```rb
query = User.where("users.field_1 > ?", 18.months.ago)
query.where("users.field_2 > users.field_1 - :time", time: 18.months.ago)
```

edit: Just saw that the values are stored as strings, then you can not use SQL.

> can not do that because the table has millions of records

I don't really understand why the size of the table limits to use the correct data type?